# How to display image which is stored on Local drive?

Tags: c#, .net, image, iis

I am saving an image inside a drive in the following path:

> D:\EdsabPmGetsDocument\images\FeaturesImage\1BBD0316AC99418EA5F7B4AECE821581.jpg.

How can I convert this file path to an address that the client can use to view the image in their browser when they type it in, such as

> 'http://localhost:5073/D://EdsabPmGetsDocument//images//FeaturesImage//1BBD0316AC99418EA5F7B4AECE821581.jpg'?"

And this is my code:

```cs
public async Task<IEnumerable<DocumentInfoDto>> DocumentFile(string featureId)
{
    var featureDocument = await _featureDocumentRepository.FeatureDocumentData(featureId);
   
    if (featureDocument is null||!featureDocument.Any()) throw new NotFoundException();
    var path = 'D:\EdsabPmGetsDocument'+ StaticPath + featureDocument.ElementAt(0).DocPath;
    var directoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(path);
    var fileInfos = directoryInfo.GetFiles("*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
        var imageInfo = fileInfos.Select(a => StaticPath + featureDocument.ElementAt(0).DocPath + "//" + a.Name);

    return (from image in imageInfo let selectImage
        = featureDocument.FirstOrDefault(a =>
            (a.DocName) == image.Split("//").LastOrDefault())
        where selectImage is not null
        select new DocumentInfoDto {Id = selectImage.Id ,
            ImagePath = image, Description = selectImage.Description, DocName = selectImage.DocName,DocExtention =selectImage.DocExtension }).ToList();
}
```

Can anyone help me to display image that image from outside project directory?

[image]

Comment: Is the image stored on the client or the server?

Comment: stored on the server for example store on my  D drive @Peter

Answer (score 0):

after searching I found how to solve this problem

```
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
{
    FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
        "D:\\EdsabPmGetsDocument"),
    RequestPath =new PathString("/Assets/Image")
});
app.UseDirectoryBrowser(new DirectoryBrowserOptions
{
    FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider("D:\\EdsabPmGetsDocument"),
    RequestPath = new PathString("/Assets/Image")
});
```

add this to your startup the then chnage you req to this:

> `http://localhost:5073/Assets/Image//images//FeaturesImage//1BBD0316AC99418EA5F7B4AECE821581.jpg`

then this work

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if you just want to provide an Folder with images, or if you want to have 'more control' over all of it.

If you just want to provide the images, one option would be to configure your webserver to provide this static files (e.g. by creating a virtual directory to your site)

If you need more control (e.g. check if requester has sufficient rights, ...) you could create another Method in your Controller and return the file there.

You can take this as a starting point:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> GetImage(string virtualPath)
{
    string physicalPath = ... // your mapping code goes here
    byte[] image = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(physicalPath);

    return File(image, "image/png");
}
```

Then all normal routing within asp.net applies.

*Note: Your application must have read permission to the file you want to provide*